# Haskell Continuation passing style index of element in list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, continuation-passing

There's a series of examples I'm trying to do to practice Haskell. I'm currently learning about continuation passing, but I'm a bit confused as to how to implement a function like *find index of element in list* that works like this:

```
index 3 [1,2,3] id = 2
```

Examples like factorial made sense since there wasn't really any processing of the data other than multiplication, but in the case of the index function, I need to compare the element I'm looking at with the element I'm looking for, and I just can't seem to figure out how to do that with the function parameter.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first let me show you a possible implementation:

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
index _ [] _  = error "not found"
index x (x':xs) cont
  | x == x'   = cont 0
  | otherwise = index x xs (\ind -> cont $ ind + 1)
```

if you prefer point-free style:

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
index _ [] _  = error "not found"
index x (x':xs) cont
  | x == x'   = cont 0
  | otherwise = index x xs (cont . (+1))
```

#### how it works

The **trick** is to use the *continuations* to *count up* the indices - those continuations will get the *index to the right* and just increment it.

As you see this will cause an error if it cannot find the element.

#### examples:

```
λ> index 1 [1,2,3] id
0
λ> index 2 [1,2,3] id
1
λ> index 3 [1,2,3] id
2
λ> index 4 [1,2,3] id
*** Exception: not found
```

#### how I figured it out

A good way to figure out stuff like this is by first writing down the recursive call with the continuation:

```
useCont a (x:xs) cont = useCont a xs (\valFromXs -> cont $ ??)
```

And now you have to think about what you want `valFromXs` to be (as a *type* and as a value) - but remember your typical **start** (as here) will be to make the first *continuation* `id`, so the *type* can only be `Int -> Int`. So it should be clear that we are talking about of index-transformation here. As `useCont` will only know about the tail `xs` in the next call it seems natural to see this index as **relative to `xs`** and from here the rest should follow rather quickly.

IMO this is just another instance of

> Let the types guide you Luke

;)

#### remarks

I don't think that this is a typical use of *continuations* in Haskell.

For once you can use an **accumulator** argument for this as well (which is conceptional simpler):

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int -> Int
index _ [] _  = error "not found"
index x (x':xs) ind
  | x == x'    = ind
  | otherwise = index x xs (ind+1)
```

or ([see List.elemIndex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html#elemIndex)) you can use Haskells laziness/list-comprehensions to make it look even nicer:

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
index x xs = head [ i | (x',i) <- zip xs [0..], x'== x ]
```

Comment: I'd rather use the type signature `index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Int -> r) -> r`. By keeping the result type of the continuation unspecified, you have less freedom to make mistakes while letting the types guide you.

Comment: @kosmikus true, maybe I assumed the `Int` to early ;) - you think it would be clearer if I rewrite it?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a value `a` then to convert it to CPS style you replace it with something like `(a -> r) -> r` for some unspecified `r`. In your case, the base function is `index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int` and so the CPS form is

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Maybe Int -> r) -> r
```

or even

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Int -> r) -> r -> r
```

Let's implement the latter.

```
index x as success failure =
```

Notably, there are two continuations, one for the successful result and one for a failing one. We'll apply them as necessary and induct on the structure of the list just like usual. First, clearly, if the `as` list is empty then this is a failure

```
  case as of
    []      -> failure
    (a:as') -> ...
```

In the success case, we're, as normal, interested in whether `x == a`. When it is true we pass the success continuation the index `0`, since, after all, we found a match at the `0`th index of our input list.

```
  case as of
    ...
    (a:as') | x == a    -> success 0
            | otherwise -> ...
```

So what happens when we don't yet have a match? If we were to pass the success continuation in unchanged then it would, assuming a match is found, eventually be called with `0` as an argument. This loses information about the fact that we've attempted to call it once already, though. We can rectify that by modifying the continuation

```
  case as of
    ...
    (a:as') ...
            | otherwise -> index x as' (fun idx -> success (idx + 1)) failure
```

Another way to think about it is that we have the collect "post" actions in the continuation since ultimately the result of the computation will pass through that code

```
-- looking for the value 5, we begin by recursing
1 :
    2 :
        3 :
            4 :
                5 : _ -- match at index 0; push it through the continuation
                0     -- lines from here down live in the continuation
            +1
        +1
    +1
+1
```

This might be even more clear if we write the recursive branch in pointfree style

```
            | otherwise -> index x as' (success . (+1)) failure
```

which shows how we're modifying the continuation to include one more increment for each recursive call. All together the code is

```
index :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Int -> r) -> r -> r
index x as success failure
  case as of
    [] -> failure
    (a:as') | x == a    -> success 0
            | otherwise -> index x as' (success . (+1)) failure
```

Comment: As a one-liner: `index x xs s f = foldr (\x' r i -> if x == x' then s i else r (succ i)) (const f) xs 0`